# How to JAXB convert when the Java class has a java.util.Properties?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a Java class with an "id" sring field and a java.util.Properties field along with its getter and setter. How would I convert an instance of this class to XML using JAXB?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you need to follow a specific XML scheme, or would *any* scheme be acceptible? Since [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) implements `Map` and JAXB knows how to serialize maps, a simple getter to return the `Properties` object as a `Map` instance might be enough. Either that getter or the default constructor would be responsible of creating an empty `Properties` object.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However, it seems it won't compile if I try to case Properties to Map.

Answer (score 0):

JAXB can handle [collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html), but a [map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) is not a collection per se. And the [entry set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29), which would be the most reasonable representation of a map as a collection, has two problems: its element type is the interface [`Map.Entry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html), and it does not support modification via the [`add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add%28E%29) method. The former problem can be circumvented via an adapter, but the latter makes relying on the JAXB handling of collections rather problematic.

It can be [done using a custom collection class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19527651/1468366). Buf if you don't want to write your own collection, then I suggest you use an [`XmlAdapter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html) to create an alternate representation of the whole [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) object. If you want to, you can design it in such a way that it models the XML scheme used by [`Properties.storeToXML`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#storeToXML%28java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String%29) and [`Properties.loadFromXML`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#loadFromXML%28java.io.InputStream%29). Something like this:

```
@XmlType(name="property") class XmlProperty {
    @XmlAttribute public String key;
    @XmlValue public String value;
}

@XmlType(name="properties") class XmlProperties {
    @XmlElement(name="entry") public Collection<XmlProperty> entries
        = new ArrayList<XmlProperty>();
}

// for use with a @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(PropertiesAdapter.class) annotation
class PropertiesAdapter extends XmlAdapter<XmlProperties, Properties> {
    public XmlProperties marshal(Properties props) {
        XmlProperties xml = new XmlProperties();
        for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> entry: props.entrySet()) {
            XmlProperty xmlEntry = new XmlProperty();
            xmlEntry.key = entry.getKey().toString();
            xmlEntry.value = entry.getValue().toString();
            xml.entries.add(xmlEntry);
        }
        return xml;
    }
    public Properties unmarshal(XmlProperties xml) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        for (XmlProperty entry: xml.entries)
            props.setProperty(entry.key, entry.value);
        return props;
    }
}
```

I've also written [a small executable demo snippet](http://ideone.com/miZSYM) which uses this to serialize a class like the one you describe, with an id in addition to a properties member. The accessors were written like this:

```
@XmlElement
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(PropertiesAdapter.class)
public Properties getProperties() { return props; }
public void setProperties(Properties props) { this.props.putAll(props); }
```

Note that the whole `Properties` field is serialized as a *single* `<properties>` element, which in turn contains an arbitrary number of `<entry>` elements. If you would prefer the entries as immediate children of your class element, then you'd have to rely on `Collection` serialization, and implement your own collection to encapsulate the properties.

Answer (score 0):

Since JAXB apparently can handle [collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html), but not [maps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), you can provide your own collection view of the [properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) field, based on [`AbstractCollection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html).

```
@XmlType(name="property") class XmlProperty {
    @XmlAttribute public String key;
    @XmlValue public String value;
}

class XmlProperties extends AbstractCollection<XmlProperty> {
    private final Properties props;
    public XmlProperties(Properties props) { this.props = props; }
    public int size() { return props.size(); }
    public Iterator<XmlProperty> iterator() {
        return new XmlPropertyIterator(props.entrySet().iterator());
    }
    public boolean add(XmlProperty xml) {
        return !xml.value.equals(props.setProperty(xml.key, xml.value));
    }
}

class XmlPropertyIterator implements Iterator<XmlProperty> {
    private final Iterator<Map.Entry<Object, Object>> base;
    public XmlPropertyIterator(Iterator<Map.Entry<Object, Object>> base) {
        this.base = base;
    }
    public boolean hasNext() { return base.hasNext(); }
    public void remove() { base.remove(); }
    public XmlProperty next() {
        Map.Entry<?, ?> entry = base.next();
        XmlProperty xml = new XmlProperty();
        xml.key = entry.getKey().toString();
        xml.value = entry.getValue().toString();
        return xml;
    }
}
```

You can have a getter of type `Collection<XmlProperty>` return a `XmlProperties` object which wraps your `Properties` field.

I've again provided [an executable demo of this code](http://ideone.com/Mztb1W). It has a class like the one you described, with an identifier and a properties field. The properties field is modeled using

```
@XmlElement(name="property")
public Collection<XmlProperty> getProperties() {
    return new XmlProperties(props);
}
```

Note that the individual entries of the `Properties` collection will be direct children of the element representing your containing class. If this should be undesirable, you can use an [`@XmlElementWrapper`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementWrapper.html) annotation to provide a wrapper element around them.

Comparing this answer to [my first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19527334/1468366), it appears to be more efficient since it only converts one map entry at a time, and it also appears to be more flexible with respect to whether or not you want an XML element wrapped around the whole set of properties.